# Flutter : BottomNavigationbar get passed along with other variables while doing Navigation.push

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to include Bottomnavigationbar to my app .This the list of pages that I navigate through :

```
List<Widget> pageList = [home(), draft(), Profile()];
```

I only want to show the bottomnavigationbar in these 3 pages .Inside the home screen I navigate to a comment screen through Navigation.push and I pass certain values into it like this:

```
 Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => comment(
                                          body: document['body'],
                                          title: document['title'],
                                          date: document['date'],
                                        )),
                              );
```

However my bottomnavigationbar is shown in comment screen also .I think it is because I am passing values inside push() method from home() to comment().How can I hide the navigationbar in comment screen ?

[image]

The comment box already have a navigationbar.

This is my bottomnavigationbar code

```
class _mainscreenState extends State<mainscreen> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  List<Widget> pageList = [home(), draft(), Profile()];
  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: pageList.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline_sharp),
            label: 'Create',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            label: 'Profile',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear; what you are you trying to do exactly? Hide the bottom navigation when pushing to a new screen?

Comment: yes,When I push to a new screen the bottom navigation is also showing. I think it's because I'm passing values to newscreen through navigation.push

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to hide Bottom Navigation Bar on new screen in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61808268/how-to-hide-bottom-navigation-bar-on-new-screen-in-flutter)

Comment: No it didn't,the bottomnavigation is still showing .But I have this problem with comment screen only which is pushed from home() screen .The home screen is passing certain values into comment screen. thats why I think its because of the way I am passing values inside Navigation.push()

Comment: No, its not due to passing arguments.

Comment: Oh I got it . I added rootnavigator :true